# PlotLabel colliding with AxesLabel

Tags: plotting, labeling

I'm having some trouble with `PlotLabel` overlapping with `AxesLabel`, when the values of the points being plotted are large in absolute size. 
The following example shows my issue:

```
e = 10^17;
GraphicsRow[{ListLinePlot[{{-1 e, -4 e}, {2 e, -8 e}, {3 e, 3 e}, {-2 e, 1 e}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"xxxx", "yyyy"}, PlotLabel -> "Label that should not overlap"]}]
```

[image: plot with labels superimposed]

Without the `GraphicsRow`, the labels don't overlap until I resize the image, at which point the label jumps down to overlap the axis label. For smaller values of `e`, I have no issues.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround to fix this automatically? My actual use-case includes the showing of two plots in a `GraphicsRow`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Adding the option `ImagePadding -> Scaled[.1]` prevents the issue:

```
llp2 = ListLinePlot[{{-1 e, -4 e}, {2 e, -8 e}, {3 e, 3 e}, {-2 e, 1 e}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"xxxx", "yyyy"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Label that should not overlap", 
 ImagePadding -> Scaled[.1]];
GraphicsRow[{llp2, llp2}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can add the plot labels using `Labeled`:

```
ListLinePlot[{{-1 e, -4 e}, {2 e, -8 e}, {3 e, 3 e}, {-2 e, 1 e}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"xxxx", "yyyy"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Label that should not overlap"]
```

[image]

```
llp = Labeled[ListLinePlot[{{-1 e, -4 e}, {2 e, -8 e}, {3 e, 3 e}, {-2 e, 1 e}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"xxxx", "yyyy"}], "Label that should not overlap",  Top]
```

[image]

```
GraphicsRow[{llp, llp}]
```

[image]

Comment: The scaled `ImagePadding` solution looks awful if you take it out of the `GraphicsRow`. I think the Labelled option is better for my need.

Answer (score 2):

Or a simple hack:

```
PlotLabel -> "Label that should not overlap\n"]}
```

or if you want to adjust the separation:

```
e = 10^17;
ListLinePlot[{{-1 e, -4 e}, {2 e, -8 e}, {3 e, 3 e}, {-2 e, 1 e}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"xxxx", "yyyy"},
 PlotLabel -> 
  Text[Style["Label that should not overlap", 
    LineSpacing -> {-1, 0}]]]
```

Comment: And why the down-vote for a technique that is extremely simple and always works?

Comment: While this answer creates excessive space between the two labels, it certainly does not merit a down-vote.

Comment: If you do that and then adjust the size of the plot manually, the plot label still jumps on top of the axis label.